# Setting up eclipse with AEM plugin

Tags: maven, aem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLxzv.png)I have set up eclipse with `aem` as plugin in it . Please help me out add /libs/foundation from `crx` to eclipse and what are the dependencies needed to be added in `pom.xml`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: any updates here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring the [website link](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/developmenttools/how-to-build-aem-projects-using-apache-maven.html?wcmmode=disabled#How-To%20Add%20Dependencies), you can use following dependency in your `pom.xml` :

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- ... -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.day.cq.wcm</groupId>
            <artifactId>cq-msm-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ... -->
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and pretty much most of the steps are mentioned on their website as well.

Comment: -I have provided an image in my problem description having my project structure. Can you please guide me where I have to put the dependecies you mentioned as all of them have pom.xml.

Comment: you should put it in the `pom.xml` of the module you need the dependency in or if you need it in all `submodules` you can put that in the `parent`'s pom.xml